# Create a Cloud SQL database from a snapshot using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

I am new to Terraform, and I am using Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL in GCP. I have a new requirement which is that I need to create the database from a snapshot using Terraform. Is it possible to create Cloud SQL databases in GCP from snapshots using Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform works with different providers in order to construct and build different infrastructure, being Google Cloud Platform one of them. You can see the entire list [here.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html)

In order to create a Cloud SQL instance using Terraform, you can take a look at the official documentation provided by Terraform on how to create a Cloud SQL instance in GCP [here.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html)

Finally, if you would like to use `Modules`, Google Cloud Platform offers different modules to work with Cloud SQL like:

- [terraform-google-sql](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/sql-db/google/3.0.0)
- You can also check it in [GitHub](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-sql-db).

I will suggest using the first approach since you can learn a lot more of Terraform by implementing the configuration files by yourself. Nonetheless, `Modules` are also a great alternative since it encapsulates the configuration files, much like a black box.

I hope this helps.